# Two predictor variables are partially related. How do I handle them before performing logistic regression

Tags: logistic, dataset, ordinal-data, data-preprocessing

I have a predictor variable which has three levels (success, failure, nonexistent). For all nonexistent values another predictor variable value is 0 but success and failure could fall within a range of 1-7.

eg:-

```
> table(variable1)
nonexistent     failure     success 
    20674        2752         956

>table(variable2)
   0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7 
20674  2975   523   148    44    13     4     1
```

In the above scenario the value nonexistent and 0 provides the same information. When variable1 is nonexistent then variable2 will be 0. My first thought was to remove one variable (both variables have a low p value) however, if I remove one of the columns some information (either variable1(success, failure) or variable2(1:7)) will be lost.

What is the best way to handle these two variables before I feed it into my logistic regression model? I am worried if I remove one of them then I lose information and if I keep both then I am flouting the no multicollinearity assumption. Is there a third way to handle the data?

Comment: Logistic models handle binary response, so 3 level Y makes no sense. If Y=0 whenever X=0 and Y>1 whenever X>1, no need to fit a model for Y=0, you know what it is. Exclude those and focus on Y=success vs Y=failure in the subset.

Comment: Both the variables poutcome and pdays are predictor variables. My target (called response) variable is different and is binary. So I am wondering how I deal with poutcome and pdays before I add it logistic model to predict response.

Comment: Having a predictor variable called poutcome is a route to confusion, I edited your question to clarify.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think you need to pre-process them before using them in your model?

Comment: @mdewey The two predictor have some data which gives exactly the same information. If I remove one of the variables then I lose information but if I keep both I am worried that I am flouting the no multicollinearity assumption. I am trying to understand the best way to handle data variables like these.

Comment: @PeterFlom I have added more information and generalised the names. Thanks for pointing out the problem.

Comment: Have you considered creating a single predictor out of all the combinations of variables 1 and 2?  It would I guess have as many as 15 categories.  But since high values of variable 2 are rare, you might find it helpful to group a few of them together -- e.g., 4 through 7 would be called ">3".

Comment: @rolando2 excuse me for the late reply. I tried your suggestion and it improved my results. thanks.